# regex remove dynamic string and keep the rest

Tags: c#, regex, web-crawler

I`d need to remove from this: http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/images_3.jpg everything between product/ and /i and keep http://example.com/media/catalog/product/i/m/images_3.jpg using regex, or c#. These are the options in a crawler app.
Please help.

Comment: Will `i/m/` be constant? Can it change? And have you tried any code so far? If yes, please post the code too.

Comment: yes, it will be always like i/m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = "http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/images_3.jpg";
var re = new Regex("^(.+/product)/.+(/i/.+)$");
var m = re.Match(input);
if (!m.Success) throw new Exception("does not match");
var result = m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value;
//result = "http://example.com/media/catalog/product/i/m/images_3.jpg"
```

Comment: I`ll check yours too in a few mins

Comment: Also it is the only answer that answers your question in the way it was stated (use a regex and get the string up to "/i") without a assuming a certain length (which was not specified in your question)

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/images_3.jpg";
int prodIndex = str.IndexOf("/product/");
int iIndex = str.IndexOf("/i/");
string newStr = str.Substring(0, prodIndex + "/product/".Length)
              + str.Substring(iIndex + 1);
```

Here's a more generic example using regex, that just looks for the portion after the 32-character hash, instead of assuming it'll be `/i/`:

```
string str = "http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/images_3.jpg";
var match = Regex.Match(str, @"(.*/product/).*/.{32}/(.*)");
var newStr = match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: I think the first one will be more generic, cause I don`t know if the hash will always contain that nr of chars. I`ll try your approach. thanks

Comment: -1 because in the 2nd code section you are hard-coding a certain length instead of looking for the characters "/i" like the question specified. The 1st code section does not have a hard-coded length but does not use regex as specified in the quesiton

Comment: Hashes are usually fixed length, so I thought ensuring that was 32 characters long was a better assumption than that the next part will always be `/i/`. From what I've seen of URLs like this, that `i` part can be any character, while the long hash will stay the same length.

Comment: Depending on what the format of the URL really is, you might do it off the length of the hash, or a `/././.+` pattern to get the last two folders, or something. With the info he told us, I think I gave a dern good guess, though. =)

Comment: As long as it works I don`t really care about your fight here. All the solutions you 2 have provided work, so I`ll mark as correct the very first of the answers. Thank you guys, also I don`t want to be a  judge in here. First wins, and that`s all. Thanks again!